# How to set $_POST[''] to data from mysql_fetch?

Tags: php, post

I have the code below that lists all of the data from columns: Firstname & Surname, I also want it so that when they are clicked it takes you to a "profile" page where you can see the rest of their data. I have made a link directly to the profile.php page and before it I set it so that $_POST = id, I'm hoping to have it so that the $_POST['id'] will be changed to the users when they click on the link.

```
<?PHP
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM members WHERE createdby = '" . $_SESSION['myusername'] ."'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$id=$row[0];
$_POST['id'] = $id;
echo ("<a href=profile.php>".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."</a></br>");
}
?>
```

It loads the page up fine and all works just it's not setting $_POST to $id.

EDIT: I'm now using $_GET["id"] which works, but it only echoes out that value I can't use it in a query:

```
$id=$_GET["id"]; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Please don't manually set the post superglobal ever. Also you are probably looking for the [session super global](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: @nlsbshtr Sure you can. But you shouldn't.

Comment: No.  You don't change $_POST - if you view it as anything other than a read-only source of data, you are Doing It Wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a value for `$_POST["id"]` will work on that very page but it does not mean that when you redirect to another page after that then your $_POST value will be automatically sent to that page. Rather you can try $_GET for this purpose. You can modify your link to be like

```
profile.php?id=$id
```

and on your `profile.php` page you can use `$_GET["id"]` rather than `$_POST`

Comment: This seems to work great, I can echo $_GET["id"] and get the id returned but when using it on the profile page to select from a table it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I'm using this code:
$id=$_GET["id"]; 
 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: is `$tbl_name` variable populated?

Comment: I have managed to fix it now, I hadn't looked but I misspelled $result as $reslt on the output code and I had to set it as an array. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use session in place of post -- `$_SESSION['id']`